# LDAP the right choice?

Tags: ldap, openldap, ssh-keys

So I'm looking for a solution for ssh key authorisation access to numerous servers, and have been pointed towards using LDAP. I wanted to present the use case and see if LDAP would be applicable and any suggestions or help would be appropriated.

Would it be possible to use LDAP to restrict access to specific servers per user/group using ssh keys. So a user tries to access a box which would bounce out to the LDAP server with the server and user details. This would then check if that person has access to that server and potentially return the correlating key to grant access.

After some research it seems possible to do the above, but I couldn't find anywhere where its for specific servers.

Also is openLDAP the best to use, I've tried setting this up and run into several issues like checksum on config files etc.

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Probably this is considered off-topic here: Therefore see my former answers: 1. [Central user management with multiple servers with SSH keys, LDAP?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/457554/301605) 2. [SSH key management in big and mixed environments (Linux)](https://superuser.com/questions/1342518/ssh-key-management-in-big-and-mixed-environments-linux) 3. [Solutions for centralized user management, sessions recording and jump server login on Linux debian](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/52211/39586)